# How to know the minimal coupling and how to find eigenvalues of arbitrary representations?

Tags: gauge-theory, group-theory, representation-theory, beyond-the-standard-model

I'm dealing with the following problem. In a $ SU(3)_L\times U(1)_X$ model, the scalar representation content accomodates the following anti-sextet

$$
S \equiv \begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1^0 & \frac{h_2^+}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{h_1^-}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac{h_2^+}{\sqrt{2}} & H_1^{++} & \frac{\sigma_2^0}{\sqrt{2}} \\
\frac{h_1^-}{\sqrt{2}} & \frac{\sigma_2^0}{\sqrt{2}} & H_1^{--}
\end{pmatrix} \in (\mathbf{\overline{6}},0).
$$

The only way I could think of to write the minimal coupling of this (in this form, and not on the 6D column vector) is considering $\mathbf{\overline{6}}=(\mathbf{\overline{3}}\otimes \mathbf{\overline{3}})_{\text{symmetric}}$ and writing a lagrangian for a bi-anti-fundamental, like

$$
\mathcal{L}^{SU(3)_L}_{\text{non-diag}}=-igW_\mu^a\left[\left(-T_a^T\right)S+S\left(-T_a^T\right)^T\right],
$$
i.e., considering it as a tensor with two anti-fundamental indices, whose generators are $-T_a^T$ -- if $T_a$ are the fundamental generators. Is this correct? My worry is that since this multiplet is elementary by definition, I'm not sure to which extent it is safe to use decomposition relations such as $\mathbf{\overline{6}}=(\mathbf{\overline{3}}\otimes \mathbf{\overline{3}})_{\text{symmetric}}$, since they are supposed to refer to multiplets constructed out of elementary ones.

I use the same reasoning to calculate this multiplet eigenvalues in order to, for instance, check its particles charges. In this model, the charge is given by $Q=T_3-\sqrt{3}T_8+X$, so that to find the charges I do

$$
\left[(-\lambda^T_3)-\sqrt{3}(-\lambda_8^T)\right]S+S\left[(-\lambda^T_3)-\sqrt{3}(-\lambda_8^T)\right]^T
$$
with the only non-vanishing component of $S$ being the particle whose charge I want to find and $\lambda_a$ being the Gellmann matrices divided by 2, which generate the fundamental of $SU(3)$.

After the breaking to the SM $ SU(2)_L\times U(1)_Y$, this is supposed to be projected as $\mathbf{\overline{6}}=\mathbf{3}\oplus \mathbf{2}\oplus \mathbf{1}$, since these 3 irreps are real. The triplet is supposed to be (which I verified checking which generators remain unbroken)

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1^0 & \frac{h_2^+}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{h_2^+}{\sqrt{2}} & H_1^{++}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

with weak hypercharge $Y=1$.

The way I have found to calculate the charges here, knowing that within the SM $Q=T_3+Y$, is to do the same as above, but now this triplet is $\mathbf{3}=(\mathbf{\overline{2}}\otimes \mathbf{\overline{2}})_{\text{symmetric}}$ of $SU(2)$.

But this leaves me with a lot of doubts. What is the difference between this triplet and a real pure adjoint triplet? This triplet cannot be written as a Pauli vector -- why is that? Why is this a $\mathbf{\overline{2}}\otimes \mathbf{\overline{2}}$ and not a $\mathbf{2}\otimes \mathbf{2}$, since the doublet is real? In the general case, how would I know how to carry these calculations on this type of matrix representation?

I'm sorry if the question is not clearly written, I'm in a deep confusion regarding these things.

**Edit**: if I multiply the $SU(2)$ triplet by the anti-symmetric tensor like

$$
\tag{1}
\Phi=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
-1 & 0 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_1^0 & \frac{h_2^+}{\sqrt{2}}\\
\frac{h_2^+}{\sqrt{2}} & H_1^{++}
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{h_2^+}{\sqrt{2}} & H_1^{++}\\
\sigma_1^0 & -\frac{h_2^+}{\sqrt{2}}
\end{pmatrix},
$$

now I can easily write it as a Pauli-vector: $\Phi=\frac{h_2^+}{\sqrt{2}}\tau^0+\sigma_1^0\tau^-+H_1^{++}\tau^+$, (where $\tau$ are the usual isospin eigenstates) and everything works fine.
I have an idea of what is happening here. I know that the anti-symmetric tensor is what relates the two equivalent pseudo-real (anti-)doublet representations of $SU(2)$, so that in Eq. (1) we are going from the $\mathbf{\overline{2}}\otimes \mathbf{\overline{2}}$ to the $\mathbf{2}\otimes \mathbf{\overline{2}}$ representation, which is the adjoint -- which can be writen as a Pauli vector.

But whether or not this is correct, It is still not clear how to write lagrangians or to find eigenvalues if someone had just given me the initial matrix and said it was a triplet.

Comment: Antisextet of SU(2)? Are you *sure* ? Why do you care about SU(3) of color if everything is a singlet under it?

Comment: @CosmasZachos it was a typo, it is a sextet of $SU(3)_L$, everything is about the electroweak sector and color is indeed irrelevant. Thank you!